# kubectl command for talking to multiple physical clusters

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeconfig

This is my `~/.kube/config` file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: https://192.168.10.190:6443
  name: cluster-1
- cluster:
    server: https://192.168.99.101:8443
  name: cluster-2
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: cluster-1
    user: kubernetes-admin-1
  name: cluster-1
- context:
    cluster: cluster-2
    user: kubernetes-admin-2
  name: cluster-2
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin-1
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/user/.minikube/credential-for-cluster-1.crt
    client-key: /home/user/.minikube/credential-for-cluster-1.key
- name: kubernetes-admin-2
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/user/.minikube/credential-for-cluster-2.crt
    client-key: /home/user/.minikube/credential-for-cluster-2.key
```

---

My understanding is, `cluster-1` & `cluster-2` are kubernetes physical clusters (`Control Plane`).

Each physical cluster has multiple virtual clusters (`Namespaces`)

If my understanding is correct, then with the above `kubeConfig`, What is the `kubectl` syntax to **get all the namespaces in cluster**?

Answer (score 2):

short answer, you can get all ns across the existing cluster in `kubeconfig`

```
for context in $(kubectl config view -o jsonpath='{.clusters[*].name}'); do 
kubectl config use-context $context ;
kubectl get ns;
done
#or
for context in $(kubectl config view -o jsonpath='{.clusters[*].name}'); do kubectl config use-context $context ;kubectl get ns;done
```

you can get **all namespace** from each cluster using below command **(current context)**

```
kubectl get namespace
```

the above will return `namespace` in the current context, so you have two cluster, its mean you will need two different context to get all the namespace from both cluster

> A context element in a kubeconfig file is used to group access parameters under a convenient name. Each context has three parameters: **cluster, namespace, and user**. By default, the kubectl command-line tool uses parameters from the **current context to communicate with the cluster**.

[organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig-context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#context)

A namespace is simply the **isolation** of the resources. for example

you can not create **two deployments** with the same name in a single namespace, because those resources are **namespace scoped**.

so you can deploy multiple deployment under `develop`, `stage` and `production` namespace.

[image]

[kubernetes-namespaces](https://belowthemalt.com/2022/04/09/kubernetes-namespaces/)

Answer (score 1):

In kubernetes there is no such thing as physical or virtual cluster. Kubeconfig consists of three parts.

- clusters
- users
- contexts

1. **clusters** - k8s clusters made of different VMs/on-prem nodes
2. **users** - users that have access to the cluster, it can be the `kube-admin` or a normal developer. user can have roles that define what resources can the user manipulate (RBAC)
3. **contexts** - a link between one cluster and one user, because you work with one cluster as a user.

Now for namespaces, they work like linux network namespaces. think of it as a house with a family living inside. If you have a Bob Newman in the house you living in, you would simply call him Bob. If the bob would be living in another house, you would reference him as Bob Newman. Namespaces logically split resources inside the cluster. You can have e.g. monitoring namespace, payroll namespace, backend namespace.
The house has different

Answer (score 1):

Hope this answer helps you:

#### Manage multiple clusters with Contexts

Let's say we have multiple clusters to administrator, so we have multiple `kubeconfig` file.

But it's not so efficent to use `--kubeconfig` option everytime with our `kubectl` command!

---

Access multiple clusters using Contexts

- Define all the clusters and users in the 1 `kubeconfig` file
- Define a context for each cluster
- We can switch between clusters using these contexts
- No need to specify kube konfig file

---

##### What is a Contexts?

In a kubeconfig file, we have:

- List of K8s clusters
- List of K8s users
- Names to reference them inside the `kubeconfig` file
- And also we have `Context`

Context

- Combination of which user should access which cluster
- Or "Use the credentials of the **kubernetes-admin** user to access the
  kubernetes cluster"
- We interact with it via either:

  - Update `kubeconfig` manually
  - or Use `kubectl config` commands

---

- How to switch the context?

  ```bash
  kubectl config use-context <CONTEXT-NAME>
  ```
- Display list of contexts

  ```bash
  kubectl config get-context
  ```
- Display the `current-context`

  ```bash
  kubectl config gcurrent-context
  ```

---

#### Namespaces in Contexts

Each context consists actually 3 components

- cluster
- user
- namespace
- By default, the `default` namespace is configured
- Other than default namespace, we need to define them

Lets say most of the time, we work with 1 specific namespace (other than `default`) and its kind of annoying to use `--namespace` for each `kubectl` command...

- Switch default namespace

  ```bash
  kubectl config set-context --current --namespace kube-system
  ```
- Now check the `~/.kube/config` file

  ```yaml
  contexts:
  - context:
      cluster: kubernetes
      namespace: kube-system # Just added!
      user: kubernetes-admin
    name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
  ```

---

- [Kubernetes Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/)
- [Certified Kubernetes Administrator](https://github.com/alifiroozi80/CKA/tree/main/CKA#manage-multiple-clusters-with-contexts)

Comment: So, `kubernetes` is a cluster that can have multiple namespaces. `kube-system` is one of that namespace, Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, **every cluster**, have **multiple `namespaces`** which `kube-system` is one of them that is going to be there by default (`kube-system` is kind of like heart of the cluster). Also you may have multiple clusters (e.g. `Dev`, `Stage` and `Production` clusters), in this case, you should use `contexts` to manage each of your **clusters**. Think `namespaces` as **virtual clusters inside the cluster** ([More resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/))